# How to use Ruby Formhelper with a SELECT element

Tags: html, ruby, forms, erb, form-helpers

Using Ruby formhelper,

I want the user to see a popup like "fill this out" when they try to submit the form with any empty fields or unselected selects.

To require a text field, this works:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :required => "required" %>
```

To require a select, I'm trying this but it doesn't work:

```
<%= f.collection_select :metric, Metric.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true, :required => "required" %>
```

The select is there and its options are populated correctly in the dropdown. But the user should see a popup if they try to submit without selecting another option besides the default "please select" - it never appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Ruby's `select` tag combined with Ruby's `options_from_collection_for_select`.  You can set your prompt to `true` or add a custom prompt and `required` must be in curly braces and its value set to `true`.  For example:

```
<%= select('trophy','metric', options_from_collection_for_select(Metric.find(:all), :id, :name),{:prompt => 'Select Metric'},{:required => true})%>
```

Where:

-`trophy` is the name of an instance variable or a model object

-`metric` is is the attribute of that instance variable. This is typically a field/column of the table whose data you're displaying.

-`:id` is the key

-`:name` is the result